# R Trouble getting correlation coefficient

Tags: r

I'm getting difficulties on my quest to get a correlation coefficient for my data set.
I started by using `ggpairs`and then `cor` function.

It might sound a lack of knowledge, but I didn’t realize that I can’t calculate the correlation for columns which type is not numeric.
For example, I would like to now the correlation between some AGE and CITY. What alternative do I have to situations like this? Or what data transformations I should do?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't correlate city to age as a numerical comparison, you would look at the distribution of age within each city as a means to identifying differences. Maybe start with boxplots.

Comment: When learning stats, watch for the difference between methods that work on numeric and categorical data. What exactly is the question you are asking of the data?

Answer (score 2):

As thelatemail put it, sometimes graphs speak more than a stat...

```
cities <- c("Montreal", "Toronto", "New York", "Plattsburgh")
dat <- data.frame(city = sample(cities,size = 200, replace = TRUE), age = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 40, sd = 20))
dat$city <- as.factor(dat$city)
plot(age ~ city, data = dat)
```

Then for proper analysis you have several options... anova, or regression with cities as an explanatory variable (factor)... Although your question might have better responses on Cross Validated!

Btw: pls just ignore negative ages, this has been done quickly.

[image]

Comment: Has I replied to Elin, I have to be more patient and explore the possibilities by other means, and plotting will be me aprouch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you first need to answer the question of what it is you are trying to do. The correlation coefficient (Pearson's r) is a specific statistic that can be calculated on two numerical values (where a dichotomous variable can be considered numeric).  It has some special characteristics, including that it is bounded by -1 and 1 and that it does not have a concept of dependent or independent variable.   Also it does not represent the proportion of variance explained; you need to square it to get the usual measure of that. What it does do is give you an estimate of the size and direction of the association between two variables.

These characteristics make it inappropriate to use r when you have a variable such as city as one of the two variables.  If you want to know the proportion of variance in age explained by city, you can run a regression of age on a set of dummy variables for city and look at the overall R squared for the model.   However unlike r, you won't have a simple direction (just direction for each city) and it won't necessarily be the same as if you built a model predicting city based on age.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m much more cleared now about my approach. I can see now why I shouldn’t  use Pearson's or other in cases like this one. And for that I appreciate your explanation.

I was trying to find a “shortcut” to find the most related variables in my dataset. I have to be more patient and explore the possibilities by other means.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the qualitative data such as City, you can use the Spearman's correlation.

You can find more information about this correlation [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corr%C3%A9lation_de_Spearman)

It can be simply used in R with the help of this command :

**cor(x, use=, method= )**

So , if you want to use it in a simple example :

cor(AGE, CITY, method = "Spearman")

I hope that helps you

Comment: While this will give you an answer, it's not clear what it means.

Comment: I have to agree with PeterK. In this case I this a regression will be a better aprouch.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, a regression will be a much more complete approach. Yet, he can add other independent variables to get more pertinent coefficient variables.